# Laravel check if user has specific role before proceeding with other functions

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a controller like this:

```php
public function __construct() 
{
    $check = Auth::id();

    if ($check->role == '5') {
        // allow to run any other controller
    } else {
        // return view('home')
    }

    return $check;
}

public function index() 
{
    return view('admin.home');
}
```

What I want to do is whenever, `AdminController` is triggered, run `__construct` function and check if `role == 5`, if it is, proceed with the request, else return view. How can that be done?

### Edit

```php
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if ($request->role == 2) {

    } else {
        return view('index');
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

**Kernel:**

```php
protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'admin' => [
        \App\Http\Middleware\CheckAdmin::class,
    ],
];
```

**Route:**

```php
Route::group(['middleware' => ['admin']], function () {
```

Error::

> (1/1) FatalThrowableError  Call to a member function setCookie() on
>   null in VerifyCsrfToken.php (line 156)

Comment: Why not look at using middleware instead?

Comment: because I don't really know how to implementit

Comment: Than please start learning, have a look at this - 
https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/middleware#defining-middleware

Comment: well I know how to define it, I just don't know what to actually put in the middleware

Comment: Middleware makes the most sense, you can perform your check before a route is accessed etc. There's a lot of tutorials online

Comment: please see my edit? can you help me solve this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`view()` returns a `Illuminate\View\View` object, instead of a `Illuminate\Http\Response`. So instead of sending the view. Redirect the user to `index` route

Try this

```php
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if ($request->role != 2) {
        return return redirect()->route('index');
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```